# Deep learning vocabulary: images/second and step time?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, deep-learning, benchmarking

There's a table at the bottom of 
https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#optimizing_for_cpu that talks about *images per second* and *step time*, in the context of performance in deep learning.

- How does one compute images/second and step time?
- When training in Tensorflow using the Estimator API, there's a number reported as *global_step/sec*. Is this the same thing? If so, does that take into account the time required to process the input pipeline, or just the time it takes to do the forward pass through the model?

Answer (score 0):

global_step/sec means how many steps per second your tensorflow model is doing. A step is usually a minibatch. So the inverse of global_step/sec is your step time and batch_size * global_step/sec is your number of images per second.

Because these numbers are throughput numbers computed on the steady state of your model training they include the input pipeline (i.e. if your input pipeline cannot produce X minibatches per second then you necessarily have to run less than X global_step/sec).

Comment: So is a step just the forward pass, or does it include the gradient update as well?

Comment: Entire training step